# Is the: "std::string can hold '\0' character" by design?

Tags: c++, standards

The fact that `std::string` can actually hold `'\0'` characters comes up all the time. This is of course inconsistent with C-style strings.

So I'm wondering, is this by design, or is it an omission, or is it just the fact that standard doesn't forbid it and compilers allow this to happen?

Comment: I would say that C-style strings are inconsistent with 'string'.  '\0' is a valid char and using it as a terminator results in the bizzare behaviour of an array of elements where one particular value of a set of 256 is excluded. Personally, I think that the use of the null terminator is responsible for the use of slow text-based interpreted bash scripts for 99.9% of U**x 'applications' - developers are afraid to use compiled code in case their strings are terminated early by nulls in data <g>

Comment: @Martin: right on. *Not* allowing some arbitrary character is the quirk, not the other way round.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm wondering what your quarrel is. `'\0'` is just another character. There is no efficient way to forbid it in a general purpose 'char' string.
That the same character has a special meaning in C is unfortunate but has to be dealt with as every restriction that is imposed by legacy code as soon as you interoperate with it.

This shouldn't be an issue as long as you stick to code that uses `std::string` exclusively.

To address your comment we need to look at the constructor that takes a `char*` which would be `basic_string(const charT* s, const Allocator& a = Allocator())` in `21.4.2 9/10` in n3242. It says that the size of the internal string is determined through `traits::length(s)` which in the case of `std::string` is `strlen` which requires its argument to be null terminated. So yes, if you try to construct a `std::string` from an `const char*` it needs to be null terminated.

Comment: I think I didn't really phrase that correctly. I guess what I'm asking is whether `std::string` works with terminated strings (doesn't have to be NUL terminated), or just doesn't care.

Comment: Also the function `c_str()` generates a null terminated string, where null is the result of value-initialization of whatever the character type is.

Comment: @Potatoswatter Which is kinda the abstraction of the whole NULL terminated string thing. Have never thought about it that way.

Answer (score 4):

There is a set of functions that accept 'char *' arguments and assume that the string is terminated by a zero. If you use them carefully, you can certainly have strings with 0's in them.

STL strings, in contrast, intentionally permit zero bytes, since they don't use 0 for termination. So the simple answer to your question is, 'yes, by design.'

Comment: But... a null-terminated string *is* a C-style string. Or a [C-string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_string), if you will. Sure, a `char*` in C can point to a buffer that includes null-bytes, but that buffer cannot be called a C-string.

Answer (score 1):

The standard doesn't say that in case of an std::string `'\0'` is any special character. Therefore, any compliant implementation of `std::string` should not treat `'\0'` as any special character. Unless of course a `const char*` is passed to a member function of a string, which is assumed to be null-terminated.

Answer (score 1):

By design.

C also can have not null terminated strings:

```
char sFoo[4];
strncpy(sFoo,"Test",sizeof(sFoo));
```

Where `sFoo` holds non-NULL terminated string.

And it have have Null-Terminated strings that can have 0 like

```
struct String {
  char *str;
  size_t length;
  size_t capacity;
};
```

String literals are NUL terminated but this is not always refers to strings.

So having NUL terminated string is practice but it does mean that 0 in invalid character.

Comment: See the [Better String Library](http://bstring.sourceforge.net/) for C, others thought about it :)

Comment: That said, `strncpy` and `strncat` etc. *will* append a null terminator if there's room.

Comment: @KerrekSB These functions are different. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

## `strncpy` vs. `strncat`

> That said, strncpy and strncat etc. will append a null terminator if there's room.

Actually `strncpy` and `strncat` are very different:

`strncpy` writes a "NUL-filled n-bytes string" to a *n*-bytes buffer: a string whose length *l* is **at most** *n*, such that the last *n* - *l* bytes are filled with NUL. Note the plural: all last bytes are zeroed, note just one. Also note the fact that the maximum allowed value for *l* is really *n*, so there can be zero NUL bytes: the buffer may no hold a NUL-terminated string. (GCC has a non-portable function to measure such "NUL-filled n-bytes string": `strnlen`.)

On the contrary, `strncat` outputs a NUL-terminated string to a buffer. In both cases, the string is truncated if it is too long, but in the case of `strncpy`, a *n* letters string will fit in a *n*-bytes buffer, whereas in the case of `strncat`, a result of *n* letters will only fit in (*n*+1)-bytes buffer.

This difference causes a lot of confusion to C beginners and even non-beginners. I have even seen lesson and books that teach "safe C programming" that had confused and contradicting informations about these standard functions.

These so-called "safe" C string manipulation functions (the "`strn*`" family) have been very criticized in the C "secure programming" community, and better designed (but non-standard) alternatives have been invented (notably the "`strl*`" family: `strlcpy`...).

Summary:

- `strncpy` will append a null terminator **if there's room**;
- `strncat` will append a null terminator **always**.