# Reading images from file - C++

Tags: c++, image, file

I have problem reading image from file, but when there is raw text it works properly. I read, that any file can be read in binary mode, but my output is just this: \FF\D8\FF\E0 and then it stops. It stops at this character  so I am not sure whether it just can't resolve that character or what. Does anyone know what is wrong? Thanks in advance.

Here's my code

```
char* obsah;  
std::string sprava;
std::ifstream is (file.c_str(), std::ifstream::binary);
    if(is){
        is.seekg (0, is.end);
        int length = is.tellg();
        is.seekg (0, is.beg);
        obsah = new char [length];
        is.read(obsah,length);
        sprava = prepinac+"\r\n"+file+"\r\n\r"+obsah;
    }
    else exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
```

Comment: have you displayed the length ? where is the output ?  how are obsah and prepinact defined ?

Comment: char * obsah; std::string prepinac,sprava.. And I have, length is more than 1000.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sprava` is a string.  As you use `+` to concatenate its components, it manages `char* obsah` as a null terminated c-string.  So everything after the first null char will not be copied into `sprava`.

**Edit:**

You can have binary data including `'\0'` in strings (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7416539/is-the-stdstring-can-hold-0-character-by-design)).  However you need to be very careful in this approach,because whenever you'd convert your string into `char*` pointer that is processed like a null terminated c-string, a part of the string might be ignored.  And if you use your string in I/O it might also give weird results.

If you want to proceed however, you could use [`std::copy()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/copy/) and a [back inserter](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/back_inserter/);

```
sprava = prepinac+"\r\n"+file+"\r\n\r"; 
  copy(obsah, obsah+length, back_inserter<string>(sprava));
```

Here an [online demo](http://ideone.com/rkOO46)

Comment: Managing null characters in a string is possible, but you'll have to take extra care for any non string functions, conversions to c-string, and I/O (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7416539/is-the-stdstring-can-hold-0-character-by-design)).  One possible solution would to copy obsah into sprava using `std::copy()` (either resize() sprava before so that it's long enough for the copy to happen, or use a back inserter)

Comment: @Pavolmodrý I've made an edit to explain with more details